# javascript/jquery updating more than one select boxes options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I have three select boxes on a page and when someone selects an option from the 1st box, I want to update the options via ajax for the 2nd box. When someone updates the 2nd box then the 3rd box gets new options via ajax.

The problem I'm having seems to be that when the user updates the first box, I check the DB for the options I need and then in php create the new select box and replace the original one. The problem is, even though the code for the select box is the same, and the id's the same the original javascript which was watching for a change on this 2nd box no longer works.

here's the cakephp/html all the cake stuff is doing is creating select boxes.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="threeCol"><?php echo $this->Form->input('industry', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$industries, 'empty'=>'Industry', 'id'=>'industry', 'class'=>'formInputSelect'));?></td>
            <td class="threeCol" id="cateWrap"><?php echo $this->Form->input('category', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$categories, 'empty'=>'Category', 'id'=>'category', 'class'=>'formInputSelect'));?></td>
            <td class="threeCol" id="courseWrap"><?php echo $this->Form->input('course', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>$courses, 'empty'=>'Course', 'id'=>'course', 'class'=>'formInputSelect'));?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And the javascript I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
//Update categories dropdown when inustry selected
$("#industry").change(function() {
    if( this.value != "Industry" ) {
        $.post("<?php echo $this->webroot;?>categories/selectoptionsupdate", {id:this.value})
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#cateWrap").html(data);
            });
    } 
});
//Update course dropdown when category selected
$("#category").change(function() {
    if( this.value != "Category" ) {
        $.post("<?php echo $this->webroot;?>courses/selectoptionsupdate", {id:this.value})
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#courseWrap").html(data);
            });
    } 
});
```

});

And finally the php which creates the new box.

```
//UPdate the options for the dropdown on post new job page
function selectoptionsupdate() {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {   
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $id = $this->request->data['id'];
        $options = $this->Course->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('Course.category_id'=>$id)));
        $result = '';
        $result .= '<select name="data[Job][course]" id="course" class="formInputSelect">';
        $result .= '<option value="">Course</option>';
        foreach($options as $k=>$v) {
            $result .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
        }
        $result .= '</select>';
        echo 'hey';
    }
}
```

Whats the best way round this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the lines

```
$("#industry").change(function() {
$("#category").change(function() {
```

for:

```
$(document).on("change", "#industry", function() {
$(document).on("change", "#category", function() {
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You're welcome. You can read [this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to better understand the event delegation.

Comment: But basically, you changed the html that had an event, so the event is lost. That's why your code worked in the first time, but failed in the second.